# Why does "import ctask as task" fail in pyinvoke?

Tags: python, pyinvoke

When I try to use ctask as defined in the [getting started guide](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/0.12.2/getting_started.html?highlight=ctask), it fails with the following error:

```
>>> from invoke import ctask as task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name task
```

What happened to the ctask module?

Answer (score 3):

In pyinvoke 0.13.0, [all tasks are now ctasks](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/114)

Change your import to use task instead.